# Link is not functioning

Tags: php

```
 if($users) {
    while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
      $user_list .= "<tr>";
    //   $user_list .= "<td>{$user['id']}</td>";
      $user_list .= "<td>{$user['make']}</td>";
      $user_list .= "<td>{$user['description']}</td>";
      $user_list .= "<td class='text-center'>

                      <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-info'>Action</button>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-info dropdown-toggle dropdown-icon' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                        <span class='sr-only'>Toggle Dropdown</span>
                        <div class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
                        <a class='dropdown-item' href='***./edit_make.php***' target='_blank'>Edit</a>
                        <div class='dropdown-divider'></div>
                        <a class='dropdown-item' href='./edit_make.php'>Delete</a>
                        </div>
                        </button>
                      </div>

                     </td>";
      $user_list .= "</td>"; }
```

Above is dynamic table content. it has an edit button as action. I need to function that edit button to the destination link which I included in the code. but it has not opened the link. is there any issue in code?

Comment: You mean this `***./edit_make.php***`? Why the `***`?

Comment: *** generated due I Bold that part on here. At code, it is href='./edit_make.php'

Comment: How do you differentiate Edit and Delete? They just both link to the same script with no parameters.

Comment: Just try edit.php page link with both "a" tags since I not created delete function yet.

Comment: When you click the link, what happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
<a class='dropdown-item' href='***./edit_make.php***' target='_blank'>Edit</a>
```

into something like this:

```
<a class='dropdown-item' href='./edit_make.php'>Edit</a>
```

Comment: *** generated due I Bold that part on here. At code, it is href='./edit_make.php'

Comment: Yes, I tried and when I hover the button, the link is shown in status bar as well. but the link does not open when clicking it.

Comment: is the delete button working just fine? No, it also not working

Answer (score 0):

```
                      <div class='input-group-prepend'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-info dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                          Action
                        </button>
                        <div class='dropdown-menu'>
                          <a class='dropdown-item' href='./edit_make.php?id=$make_id'>Edit</a>
                          <div class='dropdown-divider'></div>
                          <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Delete</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Hi all, thanks for trying to solve my issue and just now i got the solution with this. thank you both again.